# How to run tasks at a scheduled rate that DON'T wait for the task before it?

Tags: java, concurrency, scheduledexecutorservice

Currently, I have some code that I need to run every (for example) 33 milliseconds. However, the operation that I am calling requires around 270ms. Is there a way to schedule my tasks so that they run regardless of the task before them?

I have tried implementing a ScheduledExecutorService variable and running the task at a "ScheduledFixedRate" but that currently waits for the task before it.

```
Runnable imageCapture = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            // code that takes approximately 270ms
        }
    };

executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(imageCapture, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: If you want it to run that frequently, you'll need more threads.

Comment: Is there like a formula to use, I kind of just guessed on the number. Do you think adding more threads will solve my issue? @AndyTurner

Comment: Multiply the time for one action to complete by the frequency. Equivalently, divide the time for one action by the time between two actions starting. 270/33=8 and a bit. So you'd need at least 9 threads.

Comment: But that won't work with the code you have anyway, since the javadoc says "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but **will not concurrently execute** (emphasis mine).

Comment: @AndyTurner not only 9 threads, but also 9 processors (cores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the task in two: one makes actual computations and another is executed periodically and starts the first one:

```
executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);

Runnable imageCapture = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        // code that takes approximately 270ms
    }
};

Runnable launcher = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        executor.execute(imageCapture);
    }
};

executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(launcher, 0, 33, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```